# Order divs by the ID of a child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file that recursively echos the following HTML a number of times (3 times for example);

```
<div class="container" style="float:left;">
    <div class="img"><img/></div>
    <div class="info">
        <p class="title">...</p>
        <p class="name">...<p>
        <p class="viewers" id="2042">2042</p>
        <p class="data">...</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to order these main .container divs based on the id of the .viewers tag (as you can see it's set up to copy the actual viewer count).

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: whether all these elements are in a container element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```
var $divs = $(".container");

[].sort.call($divs, function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find(".viewers").attr("id") -
           $(b).find(".viewers").attr("id");
});

$divs.parent().append($divs);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pZLY6/

That is, select all of the `container` elements, use the [array `.sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to put them in order of the id attribute of their own `viewers` element (I'm assuming only numeric ids here - for an alphabetic sort you obviously couldn't just subtract the ids), then use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to move them within their parent. I'm assuming of course that they have a common parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all these elements under one container element then

```
var els = $('#myct > .container').get();

els.sort(function (o1, o2) {
    return $.trim($(o1).find('.viewers').text()).localeCompare($.trim($(o2).find('.viewers').text()))
});

$('#myct').append(els)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jPL5M/)